# Does the script run when import or require a js file?

Tags: javascript, import, require

I know about modules in JavaScript, but it's a little difficult for me to understand.

When a JavaScript file is imported

> require or import

Are scripts that have not been exported also executed?
If yes, why can't we use variables and functions that we have not exported?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.